# Cursor Adapter for populating TextView and ToggleButton in listview

Tags: android, listview

I have the following code implemented in an Activity Class. Meanwhile, the Application crashes upon launching it.

What am I missing?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Object> {
private ListView obj;
DBHelper mydb;
SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Cursor rs = mydb.getAllAlarms();
    startManagingCursor(rs);
    String[] from = new String[]{"name"};
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.alarm_name};

    dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_row, rs, from, to, 0);
obj = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewAlarms);
obj.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

    obj.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                                long arg3) {
            //obj.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String itemVal =(String) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);

            Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
            dataBundle.putString("name", itemVal);
            Intent intent = new
                    Intent(getApplicationContext(),DisplayAlarm.class);
            intent.putExtras(dataBundle);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow (SO) is not a code example location service. If you have a specific programming problem then edit your question accordingly taking heed of [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't put the cursor in your adapter.
Change your code from this

```
dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.listview_row,
            null, new String[] { mydb.ALARMS_COLUMN_NAME, mydb.ALARMS_ACTIVATED},
            new int[] { R.id.alarm_name, R.id.alarm_activated }, 0);
```

to

```
dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.listview_row,
            rs, new String[] { mydb.ALARMS_COLUMN_NAME, mydb.ALARMS_ACTIVATED},
            new int[] { R.id.alarm_name, R.id.alarm_activated }, 0);
```

Also, instead of using `mydb.ALARMS_COLUMN_NAME, mydb.ALARMS_ACTIVATED`, just pass the column names.

Comment: Thank you for your time Lalit. I have modified the code as above, taking into account your suggestions. Meanwhile, the App now crashes upon launching it. Would you know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The only way I can help now is by checking your logcat. You need to add it.